# dynamic query getting data post python

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm doing the following , when I get to post data to the queries :

```
fields = [
'name',
'surname',
'weight',
'height',
'position',
'agent',
'nationality',
'shirt_name',
'shirt_number',
'preferred_foot',
]

if request.method == 'POST':

    filter_spec = None
    for fld_name in fields:
        value = request.POST.get(fld_name, None)
        if value is not None:
            if fld_name == 'position':
                fld_name = 'position__in'
                value = Position.objects.filter(name=value)
            if fld_name == 'agent':
                fld_name = 'entrepreneur__in'
                value = Entrepreneur.objects.filter(name=value)
            if filter_spec is None:
                filter_spec = Q(**{fld_name: value})
            else:
                filter_spec &= Q(**{fld_name: value})
    players = Player.objects.filter(filter_spec) if filter_spec else Player.objects.none()
    result = [p.get_json() for p in players]
    py_resp = {
        'meta': {
            'total_count': len(result),
        },
        'objects': result,
    }
    json_resp = json.dumps(py_resp)
    return HttpResponse(json_resp, content_type='application/json')
```

To position the query is as follows:

```
Player.objects.filter(position__in=Position.objects.filter(name=positionpost))
```

So I did as it is on top , which I am not able to implement it in the code for the nationality, since the query is thus:

```
Player.objects.filter(country__in=Country.objects.filter(nationality__in=Nationality.objects.filter(name='Espanhola')))
```

And I'm not sure how to put this in the code above
Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Both your queries can be significantly simplified. The first should be:

```
Player.objects.filter(position__name=positionpost)
```

and the second:

```
Player.objects.filter(country__nationality__name='Espanhola')
```

These will usually also be more efficient, as they are doing JOINs rather than sub-queries.

Comment: I had tried so and does not even have to be ... like ... because I'm using mongobd. But my doubt is how can I make the query of nationality, following the same logic I used to position the code presented

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Why are these queries different from any of the others? `fld_name = 'country__nationality__name'`, `value = 'Esnpanhola'`.

Comment: those queries was just an example of how they do ... to understand better, for if noticing in my code, I'm not doing so directly